# Core Data read only managed objects on thread not returning result to delegate

Tags: core-data, ios6

I need to use some core data managed objects in an NSOperation. The problem is that core data is not thread safe and apparently the object can't be loaded from the new thread. Does anybody know a good tutorial for this? I need the object read only... so the thread will not modify them in any way. Some other, unrelated entities may be added on the main thread while these objects are used in the background, but the background entities don't need to be modified at all..

Hmm seemed I fixed the background running issue, but now the problem is nothing is returned to the delegate... Why? In the thred if I nslog the results are all shown but that call to the delegate never happens

This is the code:

```
-(void)evaluateFormula:(Formula *)frm runNo:(NSUInteger)runCount{
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:2];



    NSManagedObjectID *formulaId = frm.objectID;


    for (int i = 0; i < runCount; i++) {
        NSInvocationOperation * op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(runFormula:) object:formulaId];
        [queue addOperation:op];
    }

}

-(void)runFormula:(NSManagedObjectID *)fId {

    NSManagedObjectContext *thredContext =[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coord = (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)[(PSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] persistentStoreCoordinator];
    [thredContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coord];
    Formula *f = (Formula *)[thredContext objectWithID:fId];

        NSDictionary *vars = [self evaluateVariables:[f.hasVariables allObjects]];
        NSMutableString *formula = [NSMutableString stringWithString:f.formula];
        for (NSString *var in [vars allKeys]) {
            NSNumber *value =[vars objectForKey:var];
            [formula replaceOccurrencesOfString:var withString:[value stringValue] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [formula length])];
        }
        //parse formula
        NSNumber *result = [formula numberByEvaluatingString];
    // NSLog(@" formula %@ result : %d",formula,[result intValue]);
        //aggregate results
         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(aggregate:) withObject:result waitUntilDone:YES]; // the delegate doesn't get called ... 

}

-(void)aggregate:(NSNumber *)res {
     [self.delegate didReceiveResult:res];
}
```

Comment: I am just search your question title via google and have found the answer on first page. Your question is trivial and there are so many good tutorials about that. This is one of them http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Comment: Check, please, if delegate is not nil.

Comment: Yes, that was it... ARC released the delegate